# How to refer to the value of an object from the method defined - Java

Tags: java, class, interface

So I have a method as outlined below:

```
    public interface Definitions{
      public boolean isEmpty();
    }

    public class Methods implements Definitions{
      public boolean isEmpty{
      //Insert code here
      }

      public static void main(String[] args){
      return;
      }
    }
```

This method does not take parameters/arguments when it is executed, it just has to return a boolean variable defining whether or not the original object that used it is empty or not, e.g.

```
    public class NewClass{
      public static void main(String[] args){
      Methods newObject = new Methods();
      return newObject.isEmpty();
    }
```

How would I define the method "isEmpty" in order to return a true or false value? My main problem is handling / retrieving the value of the object that uses it. Thanks in advance

One thing I forgot to mention in the question is, the class Methods implements an interface. I have fixed it above. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

might be a good idea to be able to set the state of "empty":

```
public class Methods implements Definitions {
    private boolean empty = true;

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return empty;
    }

    public void setEmpty(boolean empty) {
        this.empty = empty;
    }

    public void checkIsEmpty(ObjectTypeWhichCanBeEmpty obj) {
        setEmpty(obj.amIEmpty());
}
```

Now the million dollar question is what you're trying to do? Why not store the "empty" property in the object you want to check whether it was empty or not?

Comment: The methods class is actually implementing an interface, so i dunno if you're suggestion is possible,

Comment: the original problem didn't include that interface...nice

Answer (score 0):

You should have some class members that are actually the state of the object, for example:

```
public class Methods{
    private boolean empty = true;
    public boolean isEmpty() {
       return empty;
    }

    //Then, you can add some method that set the empty field:
    public void fillObject() {
        empty = false;
    }

    public void emptyObject() {
        empty = true;
    }
}
```